# Octave - Accessing Values in octave_value_list

Tags: c++, octave

I am working within a C++ development environment while using the Octave C++ API.

I would like to know how to access single values in a returned octave_value_list when calling functions.

For example when I am calling the clock-function im getting returned an octave_value_list which shows the following:

> 2014.0000 8.0000 22.0000 10.0000 1.0000 44.7120

I now would like to access each single value but Im somehow only able to get the year.
I am missing some syntax, maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 6):

Useful documentation to answer your question:

- doxygen for [`octave_value_list`](https://octave.org/doxygen/stable/d6/db6/classoctave__value__list.html)
- doxygen for [`octave_value`](https://octave.org/doxygen/stable/d3/d35/classoctave__value.html)

---

The values you mention are a multiple `octave_value`s in an `octave_value_list`, or is it a an array of values in a single `octave_value`  in an `octave_value_list`?

Note that a single `octave_value` is not necessarily a scalar value. It can be a an array with n dimensions, and multiple  elements. It can be a struct, a struct array, or a cell array. It basically can be anything that an octave variable can be. For example, the call:

```
foo ([1 2 3], "string", {678, "other string"}, struct ("over", 9000))
```

will create an `octave_value_list` with 4 `octave_value`s and:

```
foo ([1 2 3])
```

will still create an `octave_value_list` but with a single `octave_value`.

The first thing you need is to figure out what you actually have. You can use `octave_value_list.length()` to get an idea and you can get individual `octave_value`s by simply indexing them with round brackets `()`.

```
for (int i =0; i < list.length (); i++)
    do_stuff_with (list(i));
```

Once you get an `octave_value` you can try to convert into many things.

```
std::string   s  = val.string_value ();
bool          b  = val.bool_value ();
boolMatrix    bm = val.bool_matrix_value ();
Cell          c  = val.cell_value ();
NDarray       nd = val.array_value ();
int           i  = val.int_value ();
Array<double> ad = val.vector_value ();
```

While you can use one of the `is_x()` methods of `octave_value`, the recommendation is to check the value of `error_state` after a conversion to check if anything went wrong. This will give a more natural Octave experience and will handle conversion between different types that you'd expect in Octave for you.